# Changing the height works for two of my input fields but not the other ones. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

So i am trying to make a form field in which i require users to enter their name, email, a subject and a message. I am trying to write code through javascript where if the user hits the send button I have made and does not have any or some of the information not filled out, there will be a red border around that specific input field where they did not fill out the required information. To accomplish this, I made a class in CSS that is added onto those input fields through javascript that adds that red border and decreases the height of the input fields slightly so that the added height through adding the red border does not move the input fields out of place. Everything works fine except when I try to decrease the height of the input fields. The height will only decrease on the name and email fields but not on any of my other fields and it will consequently move the input fields out of place a little bit when the red border is added. I have tried a lot of things but I cannot figure out any solution. I will add my section of code that has this issue. Thanks in advance.

```js
var validate_contact_field = function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name_field");
  var email = document.getElementById("email_field");
  var subject = document.getElementById("contact_subject_field");
  var message = document.getElementById("contact_message_field");
  if (name.value === "" && email.value === "" && subject.value === "" &&
    message.value === "") {
    document.getElementById("valid").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("invalid").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("invalid").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML = "You did not enter any \
        contact information";
    name.className = name.className + " contact_error";
    email.className = email.className + " contact_error";
  }
}

var input_focus_name = function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name_field");
  name.className = name.className.replace(" contact_error", "");
}

var input_focus_email = function() {
  var email = document.getElementById("email_field");
  email.className = email.className.replace(" contact_error", "");
}
```

```css
span {
  color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
}

input {
  text-indent: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

textarea {
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  line-height: 20px;
  resize: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-family: 'myFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#contact_inner_div_2 {
  margin-top: 6.7%;
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}

.contact_name_and_email_fields_span {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
}

.contact_name_and_email_fields {
  width: 147px;
  height: 30px;
}

#contact_subject_field {
  width: 313px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contact_message_field {
  width: 301px;
  height: 141px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contact_send_button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 60%;
  background-color: rgb(79, 87, 170);
  border: none;
  width: 317px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text_inside_of_buttion {
  color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}

.text_align {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact_div_for_span_validator {
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  width: 317px;
}

.contact_validator_spans {
  display: none;
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.contact_error {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 146px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span id="contact_inner_div_2">
          <span class="contact_name_and_email_fields_span">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
            class="contact_name_and_email_fields" id="name_field"
            onfocus="input_focus_name();">
          </span>
  <span class="contact_name_and_email_fields_span">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"
            class="contact_name_and_email_fields" id="email_field"
            onfocus="input_focus_email();">
          </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="contact_subject_field" onfocus="input_focus();">
  <textarea placeholder="Message" id="contact_message_field" onfocus="input_focus();"></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="contact_send_button" onclick="validate_contact_field();">
            <span id="text_inside_of_buttion">Send</span>
          </button>
  <div class="text_align" id="contact_div_for_span_validator">
    <span class="contact_validator_spans" id="valid">
              Validation Passed
            </span>
    <span class="contact_validator_spans" id="invalid">
              Validation Failed
            </span>
  </div>
  </span>
</form>
```

I would have posted a JSFiddle link but for some reason it looks like my javascript was not working on it for some reason.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A span element cannot contain a div element. I'm not sure how much of the rest of that content is valid either.

Comment: I changed it to a div but it did not fix anything. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Comment: But you left it as a span and your HTML is still invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        //add the error class (border)
         field.classList.add("errorClass")

    }
    else if(field.classList.contains("errorClass")){
        //else if its not empty and has the class remove it
          field.classList.remove("errorClass");  
    }
  }
```

Then call it with

`onblur="checkField(this);"`

with your HTML elements.

Comment: I tried this but the widths of my other two input fields are still not decreasing when I want them to. Also, I would like my code to check the input fields when I click the submit button, not actively as their typing.

Comment: change onblur="" to onsubmit="" as for the width that has to do with styling. I can review later today.